# not getting data in my datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am a newbie to json and datatables.

I am getting my data in `alert(data);`.
My datatable gets initialized, but its not displaying any records in my datatable.
Am I missing something here?

```
$(function() {
  $('#Search').click(function() {

    $.ajax({
      url: "{{url_for('search')}}",
      data: $('form').serialize(),
      type: 'POST',
      success: function(data) {
      alert(data);
      assignToEventsColumns(data);
      },
      error: function(error) {
      console.log(error);
      }
    });

    function assignToEventsColumns(data){
      $('#example').dataTable({
        data: data,
        columns: [
          { title: "Name" }
        ]
      });
```

Comment: You have have a datasource to call things from. Usually something like MySQL on the back end. It can't just magically know where to pull data from.

Comment: Can you post your `data` from the `alert()`. It is probably malformed or wrong type. Put a second `alert`, after the first, to know the type, like this: `alert(typeof(data)` and of all this. --- But, by the way... Have a look at the right way to load data to Datatable using Ajax [Here](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.data).

Comment: thanks. forgot to mention that my variable data is getting json data from python (yes, i am using MySQL)

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette thanks. here is my data [{"Name": "Kim"}]. my typeof(data) returns string.

Comment: You have an html table with ID of example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of `data` is a string, when it should be an object or an array of objects.

Try this to parse it.

```
$('#example').dataTable({
  data: JSON.parse(data),
  columns: [
    { title: "Name" }
  ]
});
```